# Magento 1.9.3 is not picking up a new template from a child theme from same package

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme, parent-child-theme

Magento (Version 1.9.3) is innately picking up on the parent template file (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml), instead of the child theme's template (app/design/frontend/rwd/jammed/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml).
-I use package rwd, and inside it I have default (rwd/default) theme and jammed (rwd/jammed) theme(s).
-I have set up everything correctly in System -> Configuration -> Design (Current Package Name field = rwd, default field = jammed), and
-I also added all the files from default theme (default) into my new theme (jammed). 
-I have also added app/design/frontend/rwd/jammed/etc/theme.xml file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</parent>
```

-After all this, I cleared Magento and Cache storage, and disabled all Caching.
The Magento is still taking the old template file. I know this because of the content of the file, and I can also see it in the template hints - in the path field. What else can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by setting the permissions on app/design/rwd/jammed folder (recursively, with -R) to 777.